# Restoring a workspace at accurev

Tags: accurev

I've foolishly deleted the content of a workspace I've worked on.

I wanted to reset it and thought I'll be able to re download it again from accurev, apparently it is more complicated than that...

So I'm pretty much stuck, I have an empty directory as a workspace, any way to fix that?

I can see the stream I want to re download in the GUI.

I've already opened a workspace for it in the past so I can see I'm connected to it.

Any way to reset this workspace?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked up the `pop` command?  If you have not deleted the workspace, but just the content in the local dir, pop is probably just what you need.    `***
POP
***

   copy files into a workspace or reference tree`

Answer (score 22):

Via the command line, from the top of your workspace you can run "accurev pop -O -R ."  << don't forget the dot. This will repopulate your workspace with all the files in the backing stream. The files brought into your workspace will be from the time that you ran an AccuRev update.  The -O is for Over Write and the -R is Recursive

Via the GUI, select the top most directory, right click and select Populate. In the pop-up dialog box select Overwrite and Recursive.

Any files that you had modified, but not kept will not be restored.

Any file that are active in your workspace *WILL* be over written.

You might want to run an AccuRev update after the re-populate command.

Comment: I had the following error when running `accurev pop -O -R .`: "You are not in a directory associated with a workspace". I overcame this by, in the GUI, clicking on "Open Workspace" -> Right clicking on the said workspace -> "Edit" and going through the wizard. I was then able to run `accurev pop -O -R .` successfully.