# How to access accurev workspace from new machine

Tags: accurev

I have a workspace in accurev. Recently I had to change my machine and now I want to setup the accurev workspace on the new machine. When I access my workspace from GUI, it shows old system name saying the workspace is on old system and cannot be accessed from new machine.

Is there any way I can get the same workspace on the new machine? or do I need to create a new workspace on new machine?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done from Accurev GUI.

Goto View -> Workspace.

It will show a list of workspaces you created earlier. Select the workspace you want to modify, right-click and choose Edit. It will open a window for you to enter the path on your new machine (browse to the location on your new machine). Follow the steps clicking next button.

Clicking Finish will update the system with the chosen location and with your new machine as the host name.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've used AccuRev for years and never knew you could update a workspace to point to a new machine, the current one.

Comment: On Accurev 6.2, it should be Open Workspace -> [Workspace] -> Edit,

Comment: If you follow this procedure, you will probably need to recover missing files as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331935/restoring-a-workspace-at-accurev

Answer (score 4):

Look into "AccuRev chws":

---

CHWS

---

change the name and/or definition of a
   workspace

---

### USAGE

accurev chws -w

`accurev chws -w <workspace> [ -l <new-location> ] [ -m <new-machine> ]
    [ -b <new-backing-stream> ] [ -k <kind> ] [ -e <eol-type> ]`

accurev chws -s  ...

Look particularly at -l and -m.